# Lowering keyboard latency

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, catalina

I'm on Catalina 10.15.2 on a MacBook Pro 16-inch from '19. I don't have **slow keys** activated. Is there **any way** to **measure** and most importantly **lower** the latency of keystrokes in the laptop keyboard itself?

I suspect the default latency is in the order of ms, but still somewhat noticeable if you type fast.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to measure latency is with video and even iPhone 11 can capture 240 frames per second, so you’ll be within 5ms of measurement error.

- https://danluu.com/input-lag/

If you have noticeable lag, it’s going to be likely you can use activity monitor to see what is slowing the processor or perhaps detect you have an issue on the USB bus resetting if there’s no obvious reason why keys are buffering and not going directly to the screen.

Comment: Thanks - the odd thing is that I'm noticing this lag from the laptop keyboard directly (on a MacBook Pro 16 inch '19). Regarding your recommendation for using the activity monitor recommendation, I guess that's just eye balling it? Maybe that's the best we can do, but I'm surprised there is no other easy way of benchmarking the latency (e.g. say from the terminal)

Comment: If the system is slow, how can it tell since it will be slow to measure itself @AmelioVazquez-Reina

Comment: _"If the system is slow, how can it tell since it will be slow to measure itself"_ HW can provide very high precise measures of elapsed time across events, independently of what else is taking place in the system. A computer can e.g. log a "timestamp" (relative to e.g. CPU clock or other time sources) [upon a keystroke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_controller_(computing)), and another when e.g. process says "I handled the keystroke you sent me". In other words, a system **can** measure itself.